# is it possible to read variable values using it's annotation class

Tags: java, reflection

The following code is my annotation class

```
   import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
   import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
   import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
   import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
   import java.lang.annotation.Target;
   @Documented
   @Target(ElementType.FIELD)
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   public @interface Search {
     public String name();
     public String value();
   }
```

Following class is a normal class

```
  public class MyClass{

  @Search(name = "first_name", value = "srivas")
  private String first_name;
  @Search(name = "last_name", value = "sam")
  private String last_name;

  public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
  }
  public void setFirst_name(String customername) {
    this.customername = customername;
  }
  public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
  }
  public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name= last_name;
  }
 }
```

Here I am going to read variable values

```
public class MyService{

public void getvalues(){
    MyClass myvals = new MyClass();
    myvals.setFirst_name("Vikram");
    myvals.setLast_name("Kumar");
    for(Field f: MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields()){
                 MyClass searchfields = f.getAnnotation(MyClass.class);

            if (searchfields != null)
            System.out.println(searchfields.name()+" = "+searchfields .value());

            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following output 
first_name = srivas,
last_name  = sam,

but I am expecting.

first_name = vikram,
last_name  = Kumar,

Is it possible to read please help me if any posibility is there

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean `myvals.getFirst_name()`?

Comment: f.getAnnotation(MyClass.class); gve you back the annotation not the field

Comment: You never access the field `first_name` itself, `name()` and `value()` access the two fields of the annotation.

Comment: Thank you, Mr @Lino i am trying to read with annotation class

Comment: Sorry, Mr @rick I am not understood.

Comment: I don't know why you are giving minus voting can you tell

Comment: No, you can't get the value of a field from the annotation present on said field. An annotation is simply metadata on the field (or whatever element is being annotated). The values of the annotation are determined at compile time (though I believe there is some dynamic-ness when it comes to default values); that's why they must be constants lest a compilation error occurs.

Comment: I mean that the object that you get from f.getAnnotation(MyClass.class) is not of type MyClass but of type Search(the annotation interface)

Comment: Your example doesn't compile so it can't give you result you claim to see. Please take your time and provide proper [mcve] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

Comment: Mr @Pshemo I modified the code please check now

Comment: Did *you* check if your example compile? No because you would notice that you used `Public` instead of `public`. Also I wasn't referring to fact that your code isn't place in method, nor that method is not placed in any class, but that compiler complains about code which you already provided (and which you didn't change in your edit).

Comment: Pro-tip: generally people put proportional amount of effort in answering question as they see it was put in asking it. So please take a step back and try to write proper [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

No

Also it really makes no sense to do what you are trying to do.

The Annotation is used to perform an action at compile time, it's not a store for variable data.

You could use reflection to find an annotation and work out which variable it's related to, but it's a lot of effort when you could just use a getter to get the value of the variable without all of that hassle.